# Reverse map RDD object that contains mapPartitions within

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to map the elements inside the mapPartitions of the RDD tuples to the outer elements of the RDD tuples. I've tried various ways but keep running into problems (not allowed to use sparks dataframes/explode etc.)

The data that I want to reverse map looks like this (what reducedRDD contains):

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Double, (Int, Double))]
(451,2.7362637362637363,MapPartitionsRDD[28] at )
```

It should result in something like this (where you can see the inner sets of mapPartitions are mapped to the first two values of the 4tuple):

```
(451,2.7362637362637363,17,0.324)
(451,2.7362637362637363,49,0.846)
(451,2.7362637362637363,4,-0.127)
```

As mentioned I've tried various approaches and looked through the relevant threads here on SO, bu haven't managed.
What I hope should work is a simple flatMap:

```
val reversedRDD = reducedRDD.flatMap{case (u, a, (i, d)) => (u, a, i, d)}
```

but right now I'm getting this error:

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : (T1, T2, T3)
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Double, (Int, Double))]
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]   val test5 = test2.mapPartitions{case (u, a, (i, d)) => (u, a, i, d)}
```

The reducedRDD was created from the following objects:

```
val reducedRDD = userAverages.map( a => (a._1, a._2, globAveDev)) 

val globAveDev = userNormDev.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._3)).map{case (i, r) => (i, (r.sum/r.size).toDouble)} 

val userAverages = userRatingsForUserAve.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2)).map{case (u, r) => (u, (r.sum/r.size).toDouble)}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you end up with an RDD inside another RDD?

Comment: I did this; ```val reducedRDD = userAverages.map( a => (a._1, a._2, globAveDev))```, using these two objects```val globAveDev = userNormDev.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._3)).map{case (i, r) => (i, (r.sum/r.size).toDouble)}```, ```val userAverages = userRatingsForUserAve.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2)).map{case (u, r) => (u, (r.sum/r.size).toDouble)}```. Actually I never reduced it, but I guess the problem would be the same had it been that way around. What I'm essentially trying to do is combine globDevAve and userAverages (which has different counts) to one big RDD element

Comment: Please edit your question to add code. The code is very hard to read in the comments section.

Comment: As they don't have the same size nor contains any similarities (for "join on outer" or similar), I'm not sure how to do this. New to Scala and Spark/RDD, so it's probably simple. It can ofc be done with a nested for loop (to create all combinations between, but it is simply too slow)

Comment: You cannot put an RDD inside `.map()`

Comment: Ok. Can I solve the task using another strategy? I can also put the globAveDev inside a list inside the map, but that probably doesn't addd anything

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it using the cartesian product (method):

```
  val userCartesianProd = userAverages.cartesian(globAveDev).map{
    case ((k1, v1), (k2, v2)) => (k1, k2, v1, v2)
  }
```